# Make each user have own virtual hosts on Google App Engine?

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, virtualhost

I want to run multiple virtual hosts  on Google App Engine.
But  having trouble on how i can make each user  run his content on their own virtual hosts just the same way [Slack](https://slack.com/) does it, (for example) each user signs up at  slack.com with a USERNAME,  and then content of the user is served at USERNAME.slack.com. other examples are *.tumblr.com, *.blogger.com, *.wordpress.com
 (I use the python 2.7.9 runtime by the way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think appengine namespace api is close to what you are looking for.

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/multitenancy/